# Receiving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to fetch autocomplete suggestions

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I have an registered account with the here-api's and just today created a new apiKey, because we where still using the old authentication method.
No matter what authentication we use though, we receive an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when trying to access the `suggestion.json`-endpoint. Other endpoints work fine.
I.e. this request works fine:

```
https://geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200%20S%20Mathilda%20Sunnyvale%20CA&gen=9&apiKey={API_KEY}
```

but this fails:

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=<b>&endHighlight=</b>&apiKey={API_KEY}
```

using, the same API key obviously, with the aforementioned `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

What's also confusing me is that removing a character from the apiKey in the first request leads to a senseful response

```
{
  "error": "Unauthorized",
  "error_description": "ApiKey invalid. ApiKey not found."
}
```

Whereas doing this in the second request still just returns the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try to use `https instead of http` in your request as -

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Pariser+1+Berl&beginHighlight=<b>&apiKey=apikey
```

As Example for Javascript is also using https and which is working.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/geocoding_suggestions